Deployment Error during EasyPanel Deployment on Hostinger
I encountered an error during the deployment process on EasyPanel using Hostinger. The deployment involves setting up a Node.js environment and building a Next.js application. Here are the details of the error:
TypeError: (0, s.createContext) is not a function
...
Error: Failed to collect page data for /post/detail-3
The error seems to occur during the build phase while collecting page data for a specific route (/post/detail-3). I've checked the setup, including dependencies and configurations, but I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.
I followed the deployment steps as outlined below:
Setup Node.js environment with Node.js 18 and npm 9.x.
Installed dependencies using npm i.
Ran the build command using npm run build.
Started the application with npm run start.
I've encountered this error consistently and would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve it.
I attempted to deploy a Next.js application on EasyPanel using Hostinger. Following the deployment steps provided by the platform, I expected the application to build successfully and start running without any errors. However, during the build process, I encountered the following error:
TypeError: (0, s.createContext) is not a function
...
Error: Failed to collect page data for /post/detail-3
I tried troubleshooting by reviewing my dependencies, configurations, and deployment process, but I haven't been able to identify the root cause of the issue.
